# Show Spinning wheel image till the full page loads

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, ajax

I am using the below code:

**In Layout page inside body tag:**

```
<div id="loading">
    <img src="/images/user_profile/ajax-loading.gif" alt="Loading.." />
</div>
```

**In the start page:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      $(document).ready(function(){
      $(window).load(function(){
      $('#loading').fadeOut();
      });
      });
</script>
```

**css:**

```
div.loading{

   height: 100px;
   width: 100px;
   position: fixed;
   z-index: 1000;
   left: 50%;
   top: 50%;
   margin: -25px 0 0 -25px;
   display:block;
}
```

The problem is that the spinning image is not coming immediately, it is taking sometime due to which blank page comes and the image is displayed just before the page loads.

I want a solution in which the image should be displayed immediately and till the full page get loaded.

Comment: this might greatly help you: http://perishablepress.com/3-ways-preload-images-css-javascript-ajax/

Answer (score 5):

Though there are many ways to preload images ( with CSS / Javascript etc ), the one that has worked for me reliably for small images such as that is including the image inline via

```
<img src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhEAAQAPQAAP///wAAAPDw8IqKiuDg4EZGRnp6egAAAFhYWCQkJKysrL6+vhQUFJycnAQEBDY2NmhoaAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACH/C05FVFNDQVBFMi4wAwEAAAAh/hpDcmVhdGVkIHdpdGggYWpheGxvYWQuaW5mbwAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAAFdyAgAgIJIeWoAkRCCMdBkKtIHIngyMKsErPBYbADpkSCwhDmQCBethRB6Vj4kFCkQPG4IlWDgrNRIwnO4UKBXDufzQvDMaoSDBgFb886MiQadgNABAokfCwzBA8LCg0Egl8jAggGAA1kBIA1BAYzlyILczULC2UhACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAV2ICACAmlAZTmOREEIyUEQjLKKxPHADhEvqxlgcGgkGI1DYSVAIAWMx+lwSKkICJ0QsHi9RgKBwnVTiRQQgwF4I4UFDQQEwi6/3YSGWRRmjhEETAJfIgMFCnAKM0KDV4EEEAQLiF18TAYNXDaSe3x6mjidN1s3IQAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAAFeCAgAgLZDGU5jgRECEUiCI+yioSDwDJyLKsXoHFQxBSHAoAAFBhqtMJg8DgQBgfrEsJAEAg4YhZIEiwgKtHiMBgtpg3wbUZXGO7kOb1MUKRFMysCChAoggJCIg0GC2aNe4gqQldfL4l/Ag1AXySJgn5LcoE3QXI3IQAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAAFdiAgAgLZNGU5joQhCEjxIssqEo8bC9BRjy9Ag7GILQ4QEoE0gBAEBcOpcBA0DoxSK/e8LRIHn+i1cK0IyKdg0VAoljYIg+GgnRrwVS/8IAkICyosBIQpBAMoKy9dImxPhS+GKkFrkX+TigtLlIyKXUF+NjagNiEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAABWwgIAICaRhlOY4EIgjH8R7LKhKHGwsMvb4AAy3WODBIBBKCsYA9TjuhDNDKEVSERezQEL0WrhXucRUQGuik7bFlngzqVW9LMl9XWvLdjFaJtDFqZ1cEZUB0dUgvL3dgP4WJZn4jkomWNpSTIyEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAABX4gIAICuSxlOY6CIgiD8RrEKgqGOwxwUrMlAoSwIzAGpJpgoSDAGifDY5kopBYDlEpAQBwevxfBtRIUGi8xwWkDNBCIwmC9Vq0aiQQDQuK+VgQPDXV9hCJjBwcFYU5pLwwHXQcMKSmNLQcIAExlbH8JBwttaX0ABAcNbWVbKyEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAABXkgIAICSRBlOY7CIghN8zbEKsKoIjdFzZaEgUBHKChMJtRwcWpAWoWnifm6ESAMhO8lQK0EEAV3rFopIBCEcGwDKAqPh4HUrY4ICHH1dSoTFgcHUiZjBhAJB2AHDykpKAwHAwdzf19KkASIPl9cDgcnDkdtNwiMJCshACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAV3ICACAkkQZTmOAiosiyAoxCq+KPxCNVsSMRgBsiClWrLTSWFoIQZHl6pleBh6suxKMIhlvzbAwkBWfFWrBQTxNLq2RG2yhSUkDs2b63AYDAoJXAcFRwADeAkJDX0AQCsEfAQMDAIPBz0rCgcxky0JRWE1AmwpKyEAIfkECQoAAAAsAAAAABAAEAAABXkgIAICKZzkqJ4nQZxLqZKv4NqNLKK2/Q4Ek4lFXChsg5ypJjs1II3gEDUSRInEGYAw6B6zM4JhrDAtEosVkLUtHA7RHaHAGJQEjsODcEg0FBAFVgkQJQ1pAwcDDw8KcFtSInwJAowCCA6RIwqZAgkPNgVpWndjdyohACH5BAkKAAAALAAAAAAQABAAAAV5ICACAimc5KieLEuUKvm2xAKLqDCfC2GaO9eL0LABWTiBYmA06W6kHgvCqEJiAIJiu3gcvgUsscHUERm+kaCxyxa+zRPk0SgJEgfIvbAdIAQLCAYlCj4DBw0IBQsMCjIqBAcPAooCBg9pKgsJLwUFOhCZKyQDA3YqIQAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAAFdSAgAgIpnOSonmxbqiThCrJKEHFbo8JxDDOZYFFb+A41E4H4OhkOipXwBElYITDAckFEOBgMQ3arkMkUBdxIUGZpEb7kaQBRlASPg0FQQHAbEEMGDSVEAA1QBhAED1E0NgwFAooCDWljaQIQCE5qMHcNhCkjIQAh+QQJCgAAACwAAAAAEAAQAAAFeSAgAgIpnOSoLgxxvqgKLEcCC65KEAByKK8cSpA4DAiHQ/DkKhGKh4ZCtCyZGo6F6iYYPAqFgYy02xkSaLEMV34tELyRYNEsCQyHlvWkGCzsPgMCEAY7Cg04Uk48LAsDhRA8MVQPEF0GAgqYYwSRlycNcWskCkApIyEAOwAAAAAAAAAAAA==" alt="Loading..." />
```

( Note: the above is a real loading spinner from [AjaxLoad](http://www.ajaxload.info/) )

It might not be the most readable, but it is definently loaded with the document. Assuming it's simple ( less than ~2Kb ) it should not impact your performance at all.

Comment: How do you convert the image to base64?

Answer (score 1):

You should make sure that you don't have a massive blocking javascript in your head. Move all your javascript to the bottom of the page. Also set the async attribute on the scripts if your code is properly written for that, otherwise set the defer attribute.

When this is done you make sure that your loading screen is the first element in your body, this ensures that the resources will be fetched early on. If you have many css loads, fonts etc before your loading animation, that is what is causing the delay in downloading the image, since the browsers outbound connections are saturated by other downloads. So try and keep your number of downloads to a minimum, or them below the important area or fetch them on demand with an asynchronous asset loader.

The best way to avoid other assets blocking the display of your loading animation is to inline all the relevant parts in the html. Inline the css right above the html for the loading screen, and maybe even inline the gif source as a base64 encoded data URI.

Answer (score 0):

Use separate instances of `document.ready` and `window.load`

Example:

### HTML

```
<img id="test" src="very_tiny_loading_img.gif" alt="Loading..." />
<img src="vary_large_img.jpg" />
```

### JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 // executes when HTML-Document is loaded and DOM is ready
 alert("document is ready");
});
$(window).load(function(){
 // executes when complete page is fully loaded, including all frames, objects and images
 alert("window is loaded");
 $('#test').fadeOut();
});
```

Working one with alert (replace with your code)

http://jsfiddle.net/3f2VS/

**Note**: I use @hexblot loading img in the fiddle, because it's a good trick to load tiny img like that ;-)

Answer (score 0):

I think as you are mentioning the code inside document.ready, it will fire after all the dom sets up .... rather use $(window).load(), then it will fire the event as soon as window loads.

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this in my html and it works. But I suggest you put them into seperate files

```
<style>
.no-js #loader { display: none;  }
.js #loader { display: block; position: absolute; left: 100px; top: 0; }
.se-pre-con {
position: fixed;
left: 0px;
top: 0px;
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
z-index: 9999;
background: url("http://smallenvelop.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/08/Preloader_8.gif") center no-repeat #fff;
```

}

```
<script src="http://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/modernizr/2.8.2/modernizr.js"></script>

<script>
$(window).load(function() {
    // Animate loader off screen
    $(".se-pre-con").fadeOut("slow");;
});
</script>

<div class="se-pre-con"></div>'
```